# Regex for the following string (digit+"dot" )

Tags: regex

ID_number: 111.2.003

^ I need help creating a regex that will select anything on the logs that starts with "ID_number: " and ends with ".003" .
So the value that changes is the "111.2"

Cannot get any output with what I've tried

Comment: Check this [Demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/en/regex-tester/94d63f7eb7dc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regular expression will match strings that start with "ID_number:" and end with ".003"

```
ID_number: (\d+(\.\d+)*)\.003
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookarounds:

```
(?<=ID_number: ).*?(?=\.003)
```

Breakdown:

```
(?<=ID_number: ) # lookbehind for anything matching the literal "ID_number: "
.*?              # non-greedy match anything
(?=\.003)        # lookahead for anything matching the literal ".003"
```